# Query to include pending inserts

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can I write a query that will include pending inserts as well are records in the database?  I am using EF 4.3 Code First.

Ex.

```
Foo = new Foo { Bar = 5 };
dbContext.Set<Foo>.Add(foo);

IEnumerable<Foo> foos = dbContext.Set<Foo>.Where(f => f.Bar == 5).ToList();

ActOnFoos(foos);

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I want `foos` to include both the records in the database as well as the records that are pending insert.  I am only getting the values that are in the database.

In my actual code I'll have multiple Foos that are being inserted / updated before I run my query.

**Edit**

I'm looking for something that has a similar behavior to `Find`.  `Find` will check the context first, then goes to the database if nothing is found.  I want to combine results from the context and the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DbSet<Foo> set = dbContext.Set<Foo>();

Foo = new Foo { Bar = 5 };
set.Add(foo);

IEnumerable<Foo> foos = set.Local
                           .Where(f => f.Bar == 5)
                           .Union(set.Where(f => f.Bar == 5)
                                     .AsEnumerable());
ActOnFoos(foos);

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Or the better option with changing order of operations:

```
DbSet<Foo> set = dbContext.Set<Foo>();

var data = set.Where(f => f.Bar == 5).AsEnumerable());

Foo = new Foo { Bar = 5 };
set.Add(foo);

IEnumerable<Foo> foos = set.Local.Where(f => f.Bar == 5);

ActOnFoos(foos);

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this, but it looks like my only option.  I'm doing the first, but the second looks interesting.  Is there a noticeable performance difference between the two?

Comment: Depending on number of items it can have some difference because of avoiding union (it compares sets to ensure that each entity is present only once).

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to actually insert the records within a transaction, and rollback if you decide you don't want to insert them after all.

Comment: How would a transaction help?

Comment: It would allow you to rollback all the changes, in case you decide you don't want to keep them.

Comment: Let me rephrase. How does a transaction answer the OP's question?

Comment: Nothing in my question says I don't want to keep the changes.  The ability to roll back provides no benefit to me.

Comment: A transaction by itself doesn't answer the question. Inserting the values to the database does. I guess the OP doesn't want to insert the values to the database because he's not sure they should be inserted, hence the transaction - commit when sure, rollback otherwise.

Comment: Oh, in that case, just insert the records to the database before querying again.

Comment: @zmbq The automatic flags appear only in the moderator tools. Thanks for being so quick to edit.